# OpenWRT: Set individual DHCP credentials for different clients?

Tags: dhcp, openwrt, dhcp-server

Consider a small network of clients and a router running OpenWRT. All clients are getting their IP informations automatically from the DHCP server of the router.

The devices in the network should all get the same IP credentials from DHCP-server, except for the "gateway"-information. There are 2 gateways and each client of the network needs to recieve a specific one of them. Instead of setting the gateway manually on each client, I want the DHCP server to do it.

**How do I give specific clients, different DHCP IP settings?** Is it even possible?

Comment: You mean you have *two* gateway routers in your network and you want your hosts to be assigned to use either one of the gateways?

Comment: Yes, but I want to set which client gets which gateway.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is done on OpenWRT, but DNSMasq in DD-WRT has advanced option to forward DHCP request and/or assign a different gateway: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server